# Is there any way to dial "*#06#" from my application to get users the IMEI screen within my application?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am using (swift 4.2). I tried the below code, and it does not work for me.

```
if let url = URL(string: "tel://*#06#"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            if #available(iOS 10, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        }
```

I expect the output of IMEI screen from users device but currently, I am not able to archive it.

Comment: Have you added `<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>tel</string>
</array>` in the info.plist?

Comment: No, you cannot dial URLs with # or * to prevent fraud

Comment: @chirag90 yes, I added key in info.plist file but it does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
let getIMEIScreen = "tel://*#06#"
        if let encoded = getIMEIScreen.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed),
            let url = URL(string: encoded) {
            if #available(iOS 10, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        }
```

We are not allowed to pass special characters in URL directly so we need to encode it and pass it to URL.